# Where to buy 2 Gallon or 4 Gallon carboy?

Tags: wine, carboy, glass, buying

I am looking specifically for 2 gallon or 4 gallon carboys. I have looked on eBay, Amazon, Homebrewing, and many more, but I cannot find a 2 gallon or a 4 gallon glass carboy. There might be some plastic options out there but glass is what I am specifically looking for and avoided looking at HDPE options.

Have any of you encountered or know of an online option of where I can buy this size? If you haven't are there any options for custom making them, such as from a glass vendor?

I quickly looked through this forum and didn't find this question asked, so if I did miss it please redirect me to the question if this is a duplicate. Also, the carboys of this specific size are needed for a wine experiment.

Comment: Where are you based?

Comment: Upstate NY, Geneva

Comment: Thank you all for the input!! I'll convey the findings to my colleagues and see if any of the solutions provided fits our experiment. Even though I wish there was an easier way of finding a 2 gallon or 4 gallon carboy with the same body and mouth as normal ones. I'll explore the options given regardless. I'll keep this open for a little longer in case more suggestions pop-up.

Comment: you can also use glass marbles in your 5 gallon carboy
just be careful putting them in and make sure you sterilize them.

Answer (score 1):

Northern Brewer make the "Little big mouth bubbler" and other sizes, I have seen them used in youtube videos and they look great (thick glass) and easy to clean.

I am awaiting stock to arrive to the UK so I can get a couple, and at $15.99 for the 1.4 gallon thats not too bad price for my trial runs before I go to full size batch.

https://www.northernbrewer.com/collections/big-mouth-bubbler

Answer (score 1):

I have not found glass carboys in those sizes unfortunately.  However...

I love my 3-gallon glass vase fermenter (on the right in picture below, also have a 1.25-gallon on left).  Have to be very careful with them, but they are effective, I've fermented many batches in them.  Vases allowed the smaller batch sizes while also minimizing my concerns regarding head space and head pressure during fermentation, and are reasonably easy to handle and clean if you build a simple stand and have a spray attachment in your shower (or I guess you could hose outdoors).  Just be sure to keep them well supported at all times.  Been 2 years and I haven't broken one yet.
Only $23 for the 6" OD 3-gallon one:

https://vasemarket.com/26-x-6-inch-clear-cylinder-glass-vase

https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/49378960328_be033f2c13_o.jpg

Would have to shop around probably looking for 5" diameter for 2-gallons, and might need 7" OD for 4 gallons.  I haven't looked for those sizes but you might get lucky on vasemarket.com.

EDIT: Ah... here is one that will get you very close to 2-gallons:

https://vasemarket.com/cylinder-glass-vase-24-x-5-inch

The 4-gallon will be the most difficult to find.

Comment: Wow I have never seen this before. personally would not trust it, too tall/risk of tipping over you need to build a stand (as pictured), the lack of sealing and proper venting would make me nervous and you would also need shower to clean. I am all for keeping it simple, get something that is intended for the purpose, easy to clean that fits in the sink and that comes with a lid that you can insert an air lock all for about the same price... but if it works for you, then it is all good.

Answer (score 0):

The best value glass vessel I have found is the 8litre (1.75 gallons) kilner infusion dispenser - at £15 it is very good value... drill a hole in the lid for an airlock/valve and it is 'job done'.

https://www.dunelm.com/product/kilner-5-litre-drinks-dispenser-1000066708

Answer (score 0):

Here's a wild idea. What would happen if you took a 5 gallon glass carboy and bought some paraffin, cut it up and dropped it in and set the carboy into a bath of heated water? The melted paraffin would form a layer on the bottom, reducing the volume to whatever you wanted. I don't think it would react with the wine (would it?), and getting it out would just involve another water bath. A pound costs $3.12 at Walmart and you would need 8.4 to add up to a gallon, so $28. The stuff is food grade, so what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: As this says food grade, this may be OK, but I would not be jumping at the chance to try it. I would worry about off flavours. And, my main concern would be that the ethanol may pull some paraffin into solution, and I do not want to drink praffin wax.